# How to use JSON to load data in D3 version 4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm new to D3 and I'm using it to build a simple line chart. However, much of the examples I am finding online are for version 3 and no longer work.

I have some code:

```
// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
      d.close = +d.close;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
      .data([data])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});
```

data.csv:

```
date,close
1-May-12,58.13
30-Apr-12,53.98
27-Apr-12,67.00
```

However I can't seem to refactor it to work with just a normal Javascript Array (ie):

```
let data = [
      {date: 'Tue May 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)', close: 58.13},
     {date: 'Mon Apr 30 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)', close: 53.98},
    {date: 'Fri Apr 27 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)', close: 67}
    ];
```

Also the docs aren't super clear. Which API should I be looking at? Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fiatjaf/aK6DP/

Comment: @saj Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined
Pretty sure that's a v3.x example

Comment: Whatever, they have version 5 now which I've not seen a single tutorial for, I'll just use version 3, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a conversion of [@saj's example](http://jsfiddle.net/fiatjaf/aK6DP/) to use `d3v5.x`: https://jsfiddle.net/sunny001/nrhLep72/33/

I'm no `d3` hero and have also been frustrated to see all sorts of examples based on earlier versions of `d3` which do not run in the current version but I want to work with `d3` going forward, so I think it's worth the time to understand what has changed as `d3` has evolved.

So converting @saj's `d3v3.x` example to `d3v5.x` – most of the changes involve making the syntax more concise and specific. A few examples below. There are other changes as well – compare the two fiddles. Hope this helps.

d3.v3.x

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
```

d3.v5.x (note the different `format` specifiers to handle your specific date format)

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%a %b %d %Y");
```

---

d3.v3.x

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
```

d3.v5.x

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
```

---

d3.v3.x

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);
```

d3.v5.x

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5);
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but I've honestly given up on D3, I am just going to use Canvas, I've found both ChartJS and D3 to be pretty horrible

Comment: @Antoine - really depends what your needs are. D3 is pretty awesome and powerful but for a simple chart, etc. something else might get the job done faster. Good luck!